# Why does Ubuntu start in airplane mode?

Tags: airplane-mode

Every time I start my computer, it starts in airplane mode. I have to manually turn airplane mode off. Is there a way for me to have it start without airplane mode? If it matters, I'm dual-booting with Windows.

I found this solution (https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-the-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-18-04/) for HP computers, but I'm using Lenovo, and I don't know if that solution translates to Lenovo.

After fresh restart

```
$ rfkill list  
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list` after you start.

Comment: @Pilot6
`0: hci0: Bluetooth  
 Soft blocked: yes  
 Hard blocked: no  
1: phy0: Wireless LAN  
 Soft blocked: yes  
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Please add information to your question, not to comments. As a workaround you can set running `rfkill unblock all` at startup.